# Colouring problem (with 2 colours) where each vertex has a specific area and finding min area coloured using DFS

Tags: java, graph-theory, depth-first-search, bipartite, graph-coloring

I have a list of islands/areas, initially white. All vertices connected to each other by 1 edge must have opposite colours. (Either black or white). I wish to use the minimum amount of black to colour the islands. **Each island has a different size, and index of islands start from 1.**

I have used DFS, and a global object to track both the white and black areas, then giving me the minimum of the two. Assuming the entire graph is not connected and has multiple components. I have reset the global variable for every new component. I don't get the correct answers, and I have no idea where is the mistake in my logic. (I am pretty sure my DFSrec method is correct though)

```
    // this will be the DFS spanning tree for 1 component
    private void DFSrec(int v,
                        boolean[] visitedArr, int[] predecessorArr) {

        visitedArr[v] = true;
        if (islandsList.get(v).colour.equals("WHITE")) {
            p.whiteArea += islandsList.get(v).area;
        } else {
            p.blackArea += islandsList.get(v).area;
        }

        for (int neighbour : adjList.get(v)) {
            if (!visitedArr[neighbour]) {
                predecessorArr[neighbour] = v;

                if (islandsList.get(v).colour.equals("WHITE")) {
                    islandsList.get(neighbour).setColour("BLACK");
                } else {
                    islandsList.get(neighbour).setColour("WHITE");
                }

                DFSrec(neighbour, visitedArr, predecessorArr);
            }
        }
    }


    // covers all components
    private int DFS(boolean[] visitedArr, int[] predecessorArr, int numIslands){
        int minArea = 0;
        for (int v = 1; v <= numIslands; v++) {
            if ( !visitedArr[v] ) {
                DFSrec(v, visitedArr, predecessorArr);
                int minAreaOfComponent = p.minArea();
                minArea += minAreaOfComponent;
                p = new Pair();
            }
        }
        return minArea;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Okay, the DFS answer works.**

I just realized that the problem occurred because **I didn't add in ALL the edges**, because the graph is undirected. If I add edge 2 -> 3 in the list, I needed to add in 3 -> 2 as well.